# How can I format a drive that is infected by crypto locker?

Tags: virus, formatting, format, gparted

I am attempting to format an infected SD card on my Mac to no avail. When I use disk utility, and erase the disk, it says it erased but the disk still has the same content on it. I am considering trying GParted, as I've had the best luck with it in the past. However, I'm concerned that if there's an auto run in that SD card, it may fire up in GParted's OS, and effectively spread to my windows installation. Is that a viable concern? And does anyone know of another way in Mac to solve this problem? Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Hi Dave - it is indeed a viable concern you have re autorun. My approach when working with infected media is to use LiveOS cd which will to a large extent prevent any malicious content from speeading across OSs. If you intend using GParted to repair/recover the SD card, consider using the live version > http://gparted.org/download.php

Comment: Exactly the way you normally would format pick a way and use that method

Comment: Thanks for the reply's! I went with burning the live version to a CD.